# Tab should take me to the submit button but it is not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-interface

I am using ruby on rails and I have a form with one text field, two drop down fields and one text area.

In chrome after entering the title, I can hit tab (not mouse) to go to next field. I can do all the way and I can go to submit button and then cancel.

However in firefox a tab from text field takes me to the next text area. It skips the select box in the middle. Also next tab takes me to the navigation URL bar at the top and it totally skips the "submit" button.

Here is my view code. It is in haml but you get the idea.

```
= form_for(note, {:html => {:class => 'note record'}}) do |f|
  = hidden_field_tag(:page_id, @page.altid)
  %table.form{:cellspacing => 5,:cellpadding => 5}
    %tr
      %th Title
      %td= f.text_field :title
      %td.col3= f.select :title_font_size
    %tr
      %th Body
      %td
        = f.text_area :note_body
      %td.col3
        = f.select :note_body_converter, %w(Basic Markdown)
    %tr.submit
      %th
      %td{:style => 'width:500px;'}
        .buttons
            = f.submit 'Add this note', :class => 'psubmit'
          or
            = link_to 'Cancel', '#', :class => 'cancel'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked my blog and posting a question on stackoverflow for both chrome and moz and the behavior was exactly the same as what you are describing.

Then I went to the [mozilla shortcut page](http://www.mozilla.org/docs/end-user/moz_shortcuts.html) and you will see your answer there

`Tab/Shift+Tab` next and last field

## enter

will should a form

Comment: event Shift Tab or Tab Tab is not working for in mac+firefox even though doc is saying that it should work.

Comment: FF should really change the default behavior to same as chrome.

Comment: yeah, I don't use at anymore except for testing. In terms of speed IE is even on top of FF IMO, so I'm usually on safari or chrome.